# TeXstudio: Can I put multiple packages in a separate file and still have the autocompleter recognize their commands?

Tags: miktex, texstudio, windows, preamble, auto-completion

This is a follow-up question to

- [Place preamble packages in a different tex file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339923/place-preamble-packages-in-a-different-tex-file),
- [Methods for autocompletion in TexStudio don't work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/361259/).

## The Problem

Over the years, I have collected quite the number of useful packages and commands. Until now, I had them saved with TeXstudio as a template so that I could start a new file from it. This is similar to copy-pasting everything whenever you make a new file which raises some maintainability and duplication issues.

## What I tried

I tried to separate the preamble into a test.sty file, placed it in a new root (../tex/latex/test.sty), added the root in MiKTeX Settings (Admin) and pressed "Refresh FNDB" to include it.

When I **compile** with TeXstudio, it locates test.sty and everything is fine and dandy. However, the **autocompleter** neither recognizes the packages nor their commands.

From what I gathered [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/#why-does-txs-mark-a-package-as-missing), if MiKTeX is set up, TeXstudio compares test.sty, a custom, local package, with the list of packages on the cloud from MiKTeX using `mpm.exe --list`. This may be the issue as running that command and saving its output in a temporary .txt file, my test.sty does not appear!

Am I attempting to do something currently impossible, or am I just being stupid?

Here is a MWE of my attempt, and a picture of the autocompleter.

### myTex.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{test}
%\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

% the flalign* env. from mathtools in test.sty is not recognized before compiling.
\begin{flalign*}
2x+3 &= 5 \\[1mm]
x &= \dfrac{5-3}{2}
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

### test.sty

```
\ProvidesPackage{test}[2017/10/14 The Amazing Squirrel's collection of packages]

\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage{mathtools}
\RequirePackage{amssymb}
\RequirePackage{logicproof} %Fitch-Style Predicate Logic Proof in the style of Huth & Ryan

\endinput
```

[image: flalign* is not recognized]

## Technical info.

I have TeXstudio 2.12.6 and MiKTeX 2.9 running on a Win. 7 Pro. Lenovo laptop.

Comment: I'm taking a wild guess here, but can you try setting up a custom cwl (as per my answer in the linked question), with the contents being `#include:mathtools`, `#include:amssymb` etc.?

Comment: Nice one, Troy! Adding a test.cwl file (path: %appdata%\texstudio\completion\user) with what you suggested did the trick after I restarted TeXstudio! Although I have to add every package manually to the .cwl file, I still find it amazing that they can handle packages as well as commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get TeXstudio to recognize commands from included packages (in particular for your case, included via `.sty` files), you need to **set up a custom `.cwl` file** since these files control the autocompletion feature of TeXstudio.
Refer to my [previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/361283/117534) for details on creating your custom `.cwl` files.

Here, instead of adding commands one by one into your custom `.cwl` file, since you are including packages already have their own `.cwl` files, e.g. `mathtools`, `amssymb` packages, you can use **`#include:<packagename>`** to load `packagename.cwl`.

For example, in `test.cwl`:

```
#include:mathtools
#include:amssymb
```

and repeat this for any other packages that you are adding in your `.sty` file.

Just remember to activate it via `Configure TeXstudio -> Completion` if it is not automatically picked up by TeXstudio.