# How to put everything in front of \begin{document} in a separate file?

Tags: templates, document-classes, include, renewcommand

So as I am doing a lot of similar documents I tend to always use the same preamble for all of my documents. But as I sometimes add new commands, it gets a little iffy to always remember which document has the uptodate packages, commands and such. So I would like to outsource that to a general template file, and just have new projects to refer to that for all packages, commands, settings and whatnot. But I just don't know how to do this. Can you help me with this? While googline I only found how to write different chapters and inlclude them in a main document. That's sadly not what I am trying to achieve. Thank you so much!

Comment: Does the posting [Place preamble packages in a different tex file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339923/5001) help? Two additional starting points for your research might be [Best practice on organising your preamble](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40760/5001) and [Creating a default preamble](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/278817/5001).

Comment: In addition to Mico's links you might even consider making your own package or document class (that loads the other packages, etc.) as needed. It is possible for one document class to be based on/load another. Overleaf [has a guide](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Writing_your_own_class) about this.